# Running mysql from ssh & query statement has a Text Header in the SELECT statement that needs quotes?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ssh

Thank you in advance for helping out!!!

I have an mySQL statement that works locally:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword  -e 'SELECT "Column 1 text" as "Column 1 Heading", table1.* FROM table1;' dataBase1
```

If I try and run it with SSH, it errors out.  I don't know how to get the quote in the SQL statement through SSH.

```
ssh server1 "mysql -u userName -ppassword  -e 'SELECT 'Column 1 text' as 'Column 1 Heading', table1.* FROM table1;' dataBase1"
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks,
~Donavon

Comment: The first thing I see is that your local invocation doesn't mention *mysql*, *user*, *password* or *database name*.  So from that perspective you're asking us to compare apples to pears.

Comment: can you use back ticks ` instead of single quote '?

Comment: @tink:  I updated with local mysql command.
@gtgaxiola:  back ticks make it look for a field named `Column 1 text` rather then just displaying the text 'Column 1 text'.

Answer (score 0):

try
ssh server1 "mysql -u userName -ppassword dataBase1 -e 'SELECT \"Column 1 text\" as \"Column 1 Heading\", table1.* FROM table1;' "

Comment: When I try this I get the error:  ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\"'

Answer (score 0):

After combining feedback from a few sources this is what I came up with.

Moving the select statement to the front of the command with echo and piping it to the ssh mysql command, I don't need to worry about escaping.

and it seems to work:

```
echo 'SELECT "server1" as "Server", table1.* FROM table1 INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/temp.csv" FIELDS ESCAPED BY """" TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"' | ssh server1 mysql -u root -ppassword dataBase
```